# How should I use sscanf() to break the line into fields?

Tags: c, getline, scanf

How to use `sscanf()` to separate input? here I have a `getline` to find input. I checked that input before and it is correct, which means it can read one line you input if you don't end the file. Then I was trying to separate what you input by using `sscanf();`.

- First field is a char array with no length limit
- The second field is a char array with length limit
- The third field is a integer

What I want is if I input, for example:

```
bd_21 abs 124 32152 23415
```

Then it will print out `bd_21 abs 124` because I only `sscanf` the first three elements and put them into the fields I specify. But when I run this, it shows

> segmentation fault: 11.

I don't know what is wrong here. Can anyone explain how to use `sscanf` to break lines?

My Code:

```
int main() {
    char *input = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    char *field1 = NULL;
    char field2[33];
    int field3;
    while(getline(&input, &len, stdin) != EOF){
        //printf("%s", input);
        sscanf(input, "%s %32s %d", field1, field2, &field3);
        printf("%s %s %d\n", field1, field2, field3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `sscanf` call writes to a `NULL` pointer. No [member of the `scanf` family](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) allocates memory.

Comment: You need to allocate space for `field1`, or you need to use a POSIX extension, `%ms`, and pass `&field1` so [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) allocates the memory for you.

Comment: Talking about allocating memory, the `getline` call *does* allocate memory, which you forgot to `free` and so you will have a memory leak. You will also not be able to read longer lines unless you reinitialize the `input` and `len` variables.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Are you sure?  `getline()` is always passed a pointer that could be passed safely to `free()` and it allocates more space as it needs it.  If the first line is 10 characters and the next 10 KiB, it will allocate the extra space quite happily.  Or are you trying to say something else?  (I agree about the `free()`; indeed, you need to free `input` even if the first call to `getline()` returns `-1` (if `input` is not a null pointer after the call to `getline()`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, `getline` reallocates. Still a memory leak though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will crash. allocate memory for field1.

```
 char *field1 = NULL;
```

Comment: The way to allocate memory I know is to use calloc() or malloc()? But if I don't know what size it is, how should I allocate memory for it?

Comment: @user1234567:  How big can the first field be?  Is 4 KiB going to be enough?  Or do you need to allow 4 MiB?  Allocate a suitably large size, then you can realloc to the correct size afterwards.  Or use `%ms` as I mentioned in a comment to the main question.  Not all POSIX-ish systems support `%ms` — Mac OS X 10.11 and earlier doesn't for example, and neither it seems does macOS Sierra 10.12.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   agree . :)

Comment: Thank you! I will try %ms..Even through I am still having confusion about memory...Actually I just put char *field1; at the beginning and when I run gcc to check the warning, it shows me that I need to initialize it. Why I can't just assign a value to another value?..It always make me confusing..

Comment: @user1234567  you not allocated memory for field1 . sscanf will copy and store the data in field1.

Comment: don't forgot to re-read the comment give by jonnathan leffler. you have to free the memory.

Comment: I will go to read a book to learn more about this...> < Thank you all!